# Is there a way to use readString() properly outside of the draw() function in Processing?

Tags: client, processing

Currently I have the following code, and everything is fine with it, except that I'd like to read the incoming data from host without recurring to the draw function. Specially since I don't need a draw function in the program I'm writing. While loop doesn't seem to work...

```
import processing.net.*;

String data;
Client c;
String hostvar;
String getReq;


void setup() {

  hostvar = "www.processing.org";  
  getReq = "/reference";

  c = new Client(this, hostvar, 80); // Connect to server on port 80

    //c.write("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"); // Use the HTTP "GET" command to ask for a Web page

  c.write("GET "+ getReq + " HTTP/1.1\r\n");
  c.write("Host:" + hostvar + "\r\n"); 
  c.write("User-Agent: Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.12; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021906 Firefox/3.0.7\n");
  c.write("\r\n");

  while (c.available() > 0) { // This code doesn't work. .
    data = c.readString(); // // This code doesn't work. .
    println(data); // This code doesn't work. .
  }// This code doesn't work. .
}

void draw() {

    if (c.available() > 0) { // If there's incoming data from the client...
      data = c.readString(); // ...then grab it and print it  //this code works...
      println(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you simply trying to do a HTTP GET ?

Comment: yes! Sorry. I hadn't seen someone had answered me. I stil haven't solved my issue. Yes, but I have never done it. Also, specifically what I need is to request a bunch of URLs, and then a bunch of pics (from two hosts: one for the URLs, another for the pics) the same host.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to fetch the data:

```
void setup() {

  String hostvar = "http://www.processing.org/reference";
  println(join(loadStrings(hostvar),"\n"));
}
```

Or, if you don't want to block/wait for the results:

```
void setup() {

  new Thread() {
    public void run() {
      String hostvar = "http://www.processing.org/reference";
      println(PApplet.join(loadStrings(hostvar),"\n"));
    }
  }.start();

}
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought no one had answered yet! 

Thanks. I think using a new thread will work. but I can't use loadStrings since the server needs that I identify myself as a "real browser".  Specifically I'm going to download a bunch of pics from twitter to create a poster. XD

First I'm going to request the links to the pics from twitter images, and then request the images. I'm trying to download like 300 of them. Do I need to create several Client objects for this? There are just two hosts to which I need to request this.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to probably to use Apache [HttpComponents-Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/). Download the latest 'binary' zip file from [here:](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi). Open it up and and locate all the jar files in the 'lib' folder. Then drag these directly into the Processing IDE as described [here](http://processing.org/discourse/beta/num_1241204967.html). Then you should be able to use any of the code in the 'examples' folder. Here is a simple one:

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.*;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.*;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpMethodParams;

void setup() {

  CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
  HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://targethost/homepage");
  CloseableHttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(httpGet);

  try {
    System.out.println(response1.getStatusLine());
    HttpEntity entity1 = response1.getEntity();

    // do something with the response body,
    // then ensure it is fully consumed

    EntityUtils.consume(entity1);
  } 
  finally {
    response1.close();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should also work (if you don't want to mess around with any jars), though you may need to adjust the request headers to make it look like whatever 'real' browser you want.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

void setup() {
  String s = getHTML("http://www.processing.org/reference");
  println(s);
}

String getHTML(String url) {

  String line, result = "";

  try {
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    setRequestHeaders(conn);
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader
      (new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    while ( (line = rd.readLine ()) != null) {
      result += line;
    }
    rd.close();
  } 
  catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  return result;
}

void setRequestHeaders(HttpURLConnection conn)
{
  String ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5";
  conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", ua);
  conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
  conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");
  conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
  conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
}
```